# mySQL query to update each record with combined value from all

Tags: mysql, sql

We have two tables (comment, and comment_tags) as following:

```
mysql> describe comment;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| blogpost_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| comment_text | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

mysql> describe comment_tags;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| comment_id | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tag        | varchar(80) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Each comment could have different tags associated with it. Now we want to propagate all comment tags to all comments for same blogpost. So essentially we want to make all comment_tags the same for all comments on each blogpost.

I know we can write a script or PL/SQL to do this. But I am wondering if there a single mySQL query that can do this.

Is it possible to have a single mySQL query that propagates all tags on comments to all comments of the same blog post?

Comment: Where you will get tag info from?

Comment: show complete sql code

Comment: the tags are already in the table. each comment for a blog post has different tags. we just want to each tag of a comment to all the comments associated with a given blogpost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a composite `primary key` with your `comment_id` and `tag` fields on your `comment_tags` table (which it sounds like you should), then you can use `insert ignore`:

```
insert ignore into comment_tags
select distinct c.id, ct.tag
from comment c 
  join comment c2 on c.blogpost_id = c2.blogpost_id
  join comment_tags ct on ct.comment_id in (c.id, c2.id)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c81b4/1)

***EDIT***

Given your comments, you could include `not exists` in your query:

```
insert into comment_tags
select distinct c.id, ct.tag
from comment c 
  join comment c2 on c.blogpost_id = c2.blogpost_id
  join comment_tags ct on ct.comment_id in (c.id, c2.id)
where not exists (
  select 1 
  from comment_tags ct2
  where c.id = ct2.comment_id and ct.tag = ct2.tag);
```

- [Updated Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd172/1)

Final comment -- for performance reasons, you may be better off using `left join/null` vs `not exists`.  This seems to differ between different RDBMS:

```
insert into comment_tags
select distinct c.id, ct.tag
from comment c 
  join comment c2 on c.blogpost_id = c2.blogpost_id
  join comment_tags ct on ct.comment_id in (c.id, c2.id)
  left join comment_tags ct2 on c.id = ct2.comment_id and ct.tag = ct2.tag
where ct2.comment_id is null;
```

Comment: unfortunately we don't have primary for comment_id+tag. I agree that we should. But the designed forgot to address that :(

Comment: @SaqibAli -- fair enough -- I updated the answer for a solution that does not require a primary key.

Comment: excellent. thanks! i will try it out on in development environment tomorrow. Thanks again.